# Superheating furnace stomach

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My organism lives near volcano. It  consumes large quantities of rock and digests specific minerals, expelling the remaining rock, super heated by his furnace like stomach, as lava.  What  mechanism and material my organism stomach is reinforced to create the superheating effect to create lava from rock ?

Comment: If it brings material in cool, and expels rock molten, which implies thousands of degrees dramatic increase in temperature. That's a huge amount of energy being expelled. So how is it getting energy to function?

Answer (score 3):

**More rock.**

Your creature oxidizes minerals in the rock; these are silicates but especially ferrous iron.  Oxidizing these minerals is exothermic and heats things up.  The molten slag and oxide wastes comprise the "lava" it excretes, and the chemistry that makes this organism go is hooked to the energy produced by oxidizing these minerals provides - just as our chemistry is hooked to the energy that oxidizing sugars and fats provides.

The stomach is made like a hopper.  Rocks to be oxidized line the stomach and protect the rest of the organism.  The outermost layer of rocks are those ingested most recently and they are coldest.  As one moves more centrally towards the stomach rocks are hotter and hotter.   As they heat up they are moved to the center and eventually they are oxidized by the heat and airflow there.

The airflow is key to this system because that brings the oxygen needed for the oxidation reactons.  When things are really cooking, exhaled (or since it is from the digestive tract, eructated?) gas will be hot, and possibly glowing hot - flames.

It would help if the creature could increase the surface area of the rocks before bringing them down for oxidation.  Chewing could work.  It could have super hard teeth.  Or it could have no teeth and "chew' the rocks like a bird, in a gizzard like grinding organ.

Comment: Wilk can you tell what do you mean by "super hard teeth "?

Comment: @MmmNmm Ever heard of limpet teeth? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limpet They are supposedly the strongest biological material out there.

Comment: Teeth that are harder than rocks, which presumably are normal hard.